# I would like to slice a string bounded between ${ and }

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, slice

I would like to extract the string bounded in between `${` and `}`.

Example:

```
/one/${two}
/${three}/one/${four}
/five/${six}/seven
```

I have the code were it reads the content from the json string, nothing but the API endpoints. During this process I would like to extract the words or strings bounded between `${` & `}` and store them in a variable.

Below is the same code for reading data content from a json file,

```
with open("example.json", "r") as reading:
    data = json.load(reading)
    for path, values in data['paths'].items():
        print(path.replace('{', '${'))  # If required used print statement
        for value in values:
            print(value)
```

Output:

```
two
three
four
six
```

Comment: Why not use a regex capture group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can try using `re.findall` here, with the pattern `\$\{(.*?)\}`:

```
input = "/${three}/one/${four}"
matches = re.findall(r'\$\{(.*?)\}', input)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['three', 'four']
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. i would like to understand, is there a way i can split output 'three' and 'four' save it into two different variables. Similarly i have a case were i might have 'five', six' and 'four', i want to save into a individual variable as i need to write those output into a column of CSV file.

Comment: @ArunPrasath The output from my answer is already a _list_.  You may iterate the list and assign those values to any local variables which you have in mind.